# Replacement rule for summation with Kronecker delta

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, symbolic

I want to perform some symbolic computations in index notation, without explicit reference to sums, so that in expressions of the type `f[i,j]g[j,k]` summation over `j` is implied. I often encounter the need to use Kronecker delta-symbol. Denote our implementation of the delta-symbol by `d[i,j]`. Its defining property for our purposes is that `d[i,j]f[i]` equals `f[j]` for any function `f` of `i`. Assume that in the computations only one dummy variable appears which I call 'a'. Then, the replacement pattern that comes to my mind is

```
aSum := expr_. d[a, i_]:> (expr /.a->i)
```

This works for some cases, for example

```
{1, d[a,i], f[a,j,k,l]d[a,i]}/.aSum
```

returns

> {1, 1, f[i, j, k, l]}

but also fails sometimes. The case that bothers me most, practically is the following

```
f[a]d[a,i]^2 /.aSum
```

returns

> f[a]

instead of `f[i]d[i,i]` as I would expect. Also, my replacement rule only works fine with monomials in `d`, for instance

```
f[a] (d[a, i] + d[a, j]) /. aSum
```

returns

> 2 f[a]

instead of `f[i] + f[j]` that I look for.

What is the proper way to fix this behaviour?

Comment: As for the last one, you can always use `Expand` on the expression, which makes it work. Alternatively, do `aSum := expr_. d[a, i_]:> (Expand@expr /.a->i)`. For the one that bothers you, I recommend `Trace`ing the evaluation. What happens is that it looks at the inside of `d[a, i]^2` first, so `d[a, i]` matches `expr_. d[a, i]`, which gets replaced with `1 /. a -> i`, which evaluates to `1`, so that your final expression is `f[a]`. You might want to consider adding replacement rules for powers of `d`'s. I will do this later in the day, but right now I don't have time.

Comment: Actually what you've suggested I am already using in my code. For my purposes it seems enough to use `Expand` and to add additional rule `d[i_, j_]^n_:>d[i, j]` to work with powers.  I was interested whether there is a nicer way. However, after some thinking, these two steps seem necessary. Maybe the question is not posed well enough or does not have a deeper layer. In case you write an answer I will probably mark it as accepted though.